# Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ComErrorException; cannot change properties to "Any CPU"

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-server-2008

As the title states, I am having issues with the MergeSynchronizationAgent class in C#. When I try to create my syncAgent using the following call:

syncAgent = subscription.SynchronizationAgent;

where

subscription = new MergePullSubscription();

I receive an error that states Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ComErrorException, "Class not registered". Now, I've read solutions to this problem and the most common one is to set my project platform to "Any CPU". This will fix the check out functionality of the tool but unfortunately there is other functionality in the program that looks up 64-bit databases, and setting the project's Platform to "Any CPU" breaks this look up functionality. This functionality is much more rigid than the checkout functionality so we have to set the project's platform to "x86" and have the checkout functionality work around this. My question is are there any other fixes to this ComErrorException issue where our project platform must be "x86"? I am using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you run a 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

The 64-bit installer package does not install / register the 32-bit ActiveX components. The Replication Management Objects (RMO) assemblies make use of these components when you try to access the SynchronizationAgent property.

This lack of registration is the reason why you receive the ComErrorException: your 32-bit application is looking for an ActiveX component with a specific GUID, but this GUID is present only in the 64-bit registry, which your application does not see. Should you build the "Any CPU" version, your application would run as 64-bit, and would thus see the 64-bit registry as well.

The 'workaround' for this is to get a 32-bit Virtual Machine running and install the 32-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 there. Then you will need to manually copy a set of specific files from the Virtual Machine to your development environment, and integrate the registration of these files as part of your application setup.

You can find the specifics of the workaround from the bug report filed to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/687343/inconvenient-workarounds-for-rmo-application-on-64bit-windows-7-with-32bit-sql-2008-express). The bug report targets a 64-bit application running against a 32-bit SQL Server, but the scenario is the same.